# Java DateFormat Threadsafety

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

```
final class DateHandler  
{
    private static volatile DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

    public static Date parse(String str) throws ParseException 
    {
        return format.parse(str);
    }
}
```

Because `DateFormat` is not thread-safe, the `parse()` method might return a value for `Date` that does not correspond to the `str` argument.
But replacing the `return` statement with 
  `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).parse(str);`
solves the problem and makes it thread safe.

Could some one elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateFormat isn't thread-safe because it is mutable, meaning the contents inside the object can change.  Declaring volatile in this case is just as useful as declaring it final, it would still be thread-unsafe.

The reason `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).parse(str)` works is because it is immutable.

`DateFormat` being mutable in this case is thread-unsafe because the operations of parse will set the properties of the backed mutable Calendar in a non-atomic way

So if a thread starts setting the properties of the Calendar to one date, and another thread with a separate request starts setting the properties to another date you will run into issues.